# How to create image file for x86 platform in QNX Momentics 5.0 for QNX 6.6

Tags: image, qnx, momentics

I am new to QNX. i have to make image file in Momentics 5.0. from help i came to know about process for Momentics 4.7. there are some deviations between this two IDEs.I want to make a simple application which will stand alone run on target system.for that i have download BSP file for x86 platform from QNX website.Now i dont know how to make image file. anybody know about process for making image file in Momentics 5.0? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you actually try?

Answer (score 0):

See ch. 13 of the IDE User's Guide (also Ch. 15 if migrating from an earlier version, this covers some of the differences between IDE versions) http://support7.qnx.com/download/download/26175/IDE_Users_Guide.pdf and Building Embedded Systems Ch. 3 http://support7.qnx.com/download/download/26170/QNX_Neutrino_RTOS_Building_Embedded_Systems.pdf

Also look at the overall documentation for working with BSPs support7.qnx.com/download/download/26189/QNX_SDP_6.6.0_BSPs.pdf and the specific docs for the BSP you are using.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help. Finally I am able to make image file for qnx6.6 using command line.  steps that I have follow for  x86 devices in windows :

Step -l: Download latest BSP file from QNX website.
    http://community.qnx.com/sf/wiki/do/viewPage/projects.bsp/wiki/BSPAndDrivers

Step -2 :In command promote go to "qnx660" folder and set environments variables by executing “qnx660-env.bat” file.

Step -3 :In BSP folder. You will find images, install, prebuilt, install, src folder and some make files in it. Go to images folder. You will find “x86-generic.build” file.  Edit this file in QNX IDE. Add file name that you want to run and binary file in any of the mentioned paths:

•   qnx660\target\qnx6\x86\bin

•   qnx660\target\qnx6\x86\usr\bin

•   qnx660\target\qnx6\x86\opt\bin\sbin

•   qnx660\target\qnx6\x86\usr\sbin

Step -4:In command promote goto images folder apply “make clean“ and “make” commands. Make command will generate” ifs-x86-generic.bin”  file.
                                OR
  You can also make '.ifs' file by command "mkifs x86-generic.build "anyname.ifs". anyone of this will work.

Step -5:Make your pen drive bootable. And put this “ifs-x86-generic.bin” or "anyname.ifs file into" “.boot” folder of the bootable pen drive.

Step -6 :Boot your system with this pen drive.

Enjoy….